# How to compile 64-bit libraries for qwt-6.1.2 on Windows with command line

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, qwt

We are using Visual Studio 2019, Qt5.12.3 and qwt-6.1.2 (Qwt is a graphics extension to the Qt GUI application framework) on Windows 10.  Our solution has traditionally been a 32-bit only application, but we've received a request to deliver it in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

My question is specifically related to 64-bit qwt-6.1.2.

The 32-bit version of qwt-6.1.2 is compiled without problems with the following script that runs in a batch file (no, we cannot use power shell because power shell scripts are disabled on our network).

```
cd\resources
tar -xf qwt-6.1.2.zip
rem del qwt-6.1.2.zip
cd\resources\qwt-6.1.2

REM Add the x86 path to compile qwt-6.1.2
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017\bin;

REM Create qwt make files
REM 1. Set up x86 environment
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
REM 2. Create x86 make files
qmake qwt.pro
REM 3. Compile the binaries for x86 version of qwt-6.1.2
nmake
```

When trying to compile the same source in 64-bit using the script below I receive hundreds of linker errors

```
REM Add the x64 path to compile qwt-6.1.2
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin

REM Create qwt make files
REM 1. Set up x64 environment
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
REM 2. Clean up the old qmake data for rebuild to x64
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\.qmake.stash
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\Makefile
REM 3. Create x86 make files
qmake qwt.pro
REM 4. Compile the binaries for x86 version of qwt-6.1.2
nmake
```

```
linking ..\lib\qwt.dll
   Creating library ..\lib\qwt.lib and object ..\lib\qwt.exp
qwt_dial.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_knob.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_slider.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_thermo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_abstract_slider.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_abstract_scale.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_analog_clock.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
qwt_compass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall `eh vector copy constructor iterator'(void *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,void (__thiscall*)(void *,void *),void (__thiscall*)(void *))" (??__C@YGXPAX0IIP6EX00@ZP6EX0@Z@Z)
```

etc. etc... ending with

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __load_config_used
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\msvcprt.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\MSVCRT.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64\uuid.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
..\lib\qwt.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 47 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

It appears that somewhere, something is referencing some 32-bit libraries, but I can't find any documentation (I've been searching for a few days) that specifically deal with compiling a 64-bit version of qwt-6.1.2 (or any of the related qwt versions) on Windows.

Any guidance in finding the 64-bit sources, or instructions on how to compile for 64-bit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like something in the `qmake qwt.pro` command is creating a makefile that specifically generates x86 files.

Comment: Did you try building your 64bit version **before** the 32bit version? If the 32bit version then has similar complaints you know it is an issue with the cleanup, probably the missing call to `nmake clean`? We use QWT in 64bit on MSVC for a long time and never had issues. But we only use 64bit.

Comment: @SebDieBln Yes, that was it... I was trying to call qmake clean (which doesn't work) but didn't consider nmake clean.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @BenjaminKleynhans I'm glad I could help. I posted it now as an actual answer, so go ahead and accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `nmake clean` and so there are (even after a fresh `qmake`) leftovers from the 32bit-build breaking your 64bit-build.

Comment: One additional thing to add... Since there is no working "qmake clean" one also has to delete the "Makefile"s in all the directories because qmake generates 32-bit only "Makefile"s.  I've added the build/clean script to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions in a post below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion from @SebDieBln I was able to build the 64-bit version.  There is an additional step required however.

Even though we can run *"nmake clean"* to clean the MS Build data, there is no *"qmake clean"* to clean the qmake build data.  This is a manual step.

Below is the complete script to build both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries for qwt-6.1.2 including the cleaning process in between.

**NOTE:** *This process does not install qwt-6.1.2, it only compiles 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.*

```
REM Create resources directory and extract qwt in said directory
cd\resources
tar -xf qwt-6.1.2.zip
REM Delete the zip file since it it no longer required
del qwt-6.1.2.zip
cd\resources\qwt-6.1.2

REM Add the x86 path to compile 32-bit qwt-6.1.2 binaries
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017\bin;

REM 1. Set up x86 environment
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
REM 2. Create x86 make files
qmake qwt.pro
REM 3. Compile the binaries for x86 version of qwt-6.1.2
nmake

REM Make a lib\lib32 directory
mkdir c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\lib32
REM Move the compiled files to the lib\lib32 directory
move c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\*.* c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\lib32\

REM Clean up the x86 make code
nmake clean

REM Clean up the old qmake data for rebuild to x64
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\.qmake.stash
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\Makefile*
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\moc
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\plugins
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\resources
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\doc\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\src\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\textengines\Makefile*

REM Remove the x86 path variables to MSVC2017
SET PATH=%PATH:C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017\bin;=%
REM Add the x64 path to compile 64-bit qwt-6.1.2 binaries
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin

REM 1. Set up x64 environment
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
REM 2. Create x86 make files
qmake qwt.pro
REM 3. Compile the binaries for x86 version of qwt-6.1.2
nmake

REM Make a lib\lib64 directory
mkdir c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\lib64
REM Move the compiled files to the lib\lib64 directory
move c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\*.* c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\lib\lib64

REM Clean up the x64 make code
nmake clean

REM Clean up the x64 qmake data
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\.qmake.stash
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\Makefile*
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\moc
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\plugins
rd /S /Q c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\designer\resources
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\doc\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\src\Makefile*
del c:\resources\qwt-6.1.2\textengines\Makefile*

REM Remove the x64 path variables to MSVC2017_64
SET PATH=%PATH:C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin;=%
```